# getting 404 not found when submitting form using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am new with laravel, I am having an issue when posting my data to controller in laravel while using ajax. My view contains a select box which is populated from database when a user select a value from select box i am trying to call ajax which will return details of salary of the user.The issue is it gives me 404 not found error.

The Code for the controller file is shown below.

```
    this function is defined inside a controller

    public function getPostSalary()
        {
            echo "ajax called";
            return 'true';
        }
```

The Routes file is

```
Route::post('company/salary-user', 'CompanyController@getPostSalary');
```

this is my ajax code from where the controller is being calleD

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#employee').change(function () {
            var values = $('#employee').val();
            if (values == '') {
                $.pnotify({
                    title: 'Message',
                    text: 'Please Select a User.',
                    type: 'error',
                    delay: 3000
                });
                return false;
            }
            var csrf = $('#csrf').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '{!! URL::to("company/salary-user")!!}',
                type: "POST",
                data: { user_id: values, _token: csrf },
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Can someone help me to figure out what is the issue and what should be done to call my function.

Comment: your ajax file is in *.js ? or inside your blade template ?

Comment: and in your network tracking, whats is the url you are pointed to when event `employee` change happens ?

Comment: my js file is in blade tempelate and the url it showing is

Comment: "http://localhost/attendance/public/company/salary-user".

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: Modify your route accordingly
**`Route::post('attendance/public/company/salary-user', CompanyController@getPostSalary');`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use direct url like

```
 $.ajax({
            url:'company/salary-user',
            type: "POST",
            data: { user_id: values, _token: csrf },
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#loader').hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes is for string so your url is not generating as you expecting. Use like this

```
  url : "{!! URL::to('company/salary-user')!!}",
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line:

```
{!! URL::to("company/salary-user")!!}
```

by :

```
{{ url('/company/salary-user') }}
```

or

```
{{ route('/company/salary-user') }}
```

Comment: it is giving me the same issue with that

Comment: LOL ,omg i was so dump, use either `{{ url('/company/salary-user') }}` or `{{ route('/company/salary-user') }}`

Comment: the issue is at it place

Comment: what's the actual url now you are pointed to ? and don't forget to clear your browser cache

Comment: and when using `url('/company/salary-user')` ?

Comment: http://localhost/attendance/public/company/salary-user this is the actual url to which i am pointed

Comment: when you manually access this page http://localhost/attendance/company/salary-user , do you get the same error ?

Comment: try manually use in your ajax `url: 'http://localhost/attendance/company/salary-user',` and check if the error in the route it-self or in your function used to call thelink

Comment: it is just giving me 404 not found when ajax loads

Comment: it is giving me reflection exception saying class or className Doesnt exisits

Comment: so, your issue in your route all that time, are you sure from your class name ? and the class file permission ?

Comment: add this `Route::get('company/salary-user', 'CompanyController@getPostSalary');` to your route file and check access your url from your browser again

Comment: checked with that brother.. the issue remains says